# Ind-objects with "full support"

Tags: ct.category-theory

I originally posted this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4696766/7062) on Math Stackexchange, but I didn't get an answer.

Let $C$ be a small category. Let's say a presheaf $P\colon C^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathsf{Set}$ has "full support" if $P(X)\neq \varnothing$ for all objects $X$. We could also say that $P$ is "inhabited everywhere".

Recall that an [Ind-object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object) on $C$ is a presheaf on $C$ which is a filtered colimit of representable presheaves. Equivalently, a presheaf is an Ind-object if and only if its [category of elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_elements#The_category_of_elements_of_a_presheaf) is filtered (see Proposition 4.8 [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object#recognition_of_indobjects)).

**Question:** Is there a nice characterization of those categories $C$ which admit an Ind-object with full support?

One characterization that comes from unwinding the definition is that there is a filtered diagram $D$ in $C$ such that every object in $C$ has an arrow to some object in $D$. But I'm wondering if there is some more "concrete" condition, i.e. one that doesn't involve quantifying over arbitrary filtered diagrams.

---

Here are some easy observations:

1. A sufficient condition is that $C$ itself is filtered.
2. A necessary condition is that $C$ is directed, in the sense that for all objects $X$ and $Y$ in $C$, there exists an object $Z$ in $C$ and arrows $X\to Z$ and $Y\to Z$. This follows from directedness of the category of elements of an Ind-object with full support.
3. Another sufficient condition is that $C$ is directed and there is a countable set of objects $\{A_n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ which is cofinal, in $C$, in the sense that every object in $C$ admits an arrow to some $A_n$. Indeed, then we can build a chain $(B_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by induction with $B_0 = A_0$ and such that $B_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ both admit arrows to $B_{n+1}$, using directedness. The Ind-object corresponding to this chain has full support.

But none of these implications reverse, as I'll now show.

*Example 1:* The category with two objects $0$ and $1$ and two non-identity arrows $0\to 1$ is not filtered, but the representable presheaf $\mathrm{Hom}(-,1)$ is an Ind-object with full support.

*Example 2:* Thanks to Sridhar Ramesh for providing the following example of a category which is directed but has no Ind-object with full support.

Let $S$ be an uncountable set, and consider the free category $\newcommand{\C}{\mathscr{C}}\C$  generated by the directed graph $ (\mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{fin}}(S),\subset)$. So the objects of $\C$ are finite subsets of $S$, an arrow $A\to B$ is a finite chain $(A_0,\dots,A_n)$ with $n\geq 0$,  $A_0 = A$, $A_n = B$, and $A_i\subset A_{i+1}$ for all $i$ (note that $\subset$ means proper subset), and composition is concatenation of chains.

$\C$ is directed, since for any objects $A$ and $B$, we have arrows $A\to (A\cup B)$ and $B \to (A\cup B)$: take the identity if $A = (A\cup B)$ or the one-step chain if $A\subset A\cup B$, and similarly for $B\to (A\cup B)$.

Observe that if we have a commutative square in $\C$:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>>> B\\
@VVV @VVV \\
C @>>> D
\end{CD}$$ then the composite arrow $A\to D$ is a chain containing both $B$ and $C$, so either $B\subseteq C$ or $C\subseteq B$.

Now suppose that $\newcommand{\D}{\mathscr{D}}\D\colon F\to \C$ is a filtered diagram, i.e. a functor from a filtered category $F$ to $\C$.

Let $x\in F$, and write ${\uparrow}(x)$ for the set of objects in $F$ which admit an arrow from $x$. Given $y,z\in {\uparrow}(x)$, since $F$ is filtered, there is a commutative square in $F$:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
x @>>> y\\
@VVV @VVV \\
z @>>> w
\end{CD}$$
It follows that $\D(y)$ and $\D(z)$ are comparable under $\subseteq$. So $\D({\uparrow}(x))$ is linearly ordered by $\subseteq$. Now  distinct elements of $\D({\uparrow}(x))$ must have different finite cardinalities, so $\D({\uparrow}(x))$ is countable, and $\bigcup \D({\uparrow}(x))$ is a countable subset of $S$.

If $s\in S\setminus \bigcup \D({\uparrow}(x))$, then $\{s\}$ does not admit an arrow into any object in $\D({\uparrow}(x))$. In fact, I claim that $\{s\}$ does not admit an arrow into any object in $\D(F)$. Suppose for contradiction there is an arrow $\{s\}\to \mathscr{D}(y)$ with $y\in F$. Since $F$ is directed, there is a $z\in {\uparrow}(x)$ with an arrow $f\colon y\to z$. Composing with $\mathscr{D}(f)$ gives an arrow $\{s\}\to \mathscr{D}(z)$, contradiction. Thus the Ind-object corresponding to $\D$ does not have full support.

A similar argument shows that the free category generated by the directed graph $(\omega_1,<)$ is directed but admits no Ind-object with full support.

*Example 3:* Consider the poset $(\omega_1,\leq)$ as a category. This category is filtered, hence it admits an Ind-object with full support, but no countable set of objects is cofinal, since $\omega_1$ is an uncountable regular ordinal.

Considering these necessary and sufficient conditions and the three examples, I'm left with the vague feeling that admitting an Ind-object with full support is something like "$C$ is directed, and failures of $C$ to be filtered are countably bounded somehow". But I don't know how to make this precise.

Comment: Another basic example is whenever $\mathscr C$ has a terminal object, for then the constant sheaf $\operatorname{pt}$ is representable. (I guess this is the only type of category over which I usually take presheaves...)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Right. Similarly, a category with a terminal object is trivially filtered. The original motivation for my question comes from thinking about categories of finite structures and (injective) embeddings between them. These types of categories never have terminal objects and are never filtered, except in trivial situations. But then I got interested in the general case as well.

Comment: Another way of phrasing the question is "when does a finitely accessible category have a weakly terminal object". There are [some](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weak+limit) relevant [nlab pages](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weakly+initial+object).

Comment: I might suggest trying out variants of the question like "when does a finitely accessible category admit a cogenerator?" or "when does a finitely accessible category admit an injective cogenerator?" Also, I think another sufficient-but-not-necessary condition is that $Ind(C)$ be directed and also have the amalgamation property -- I'm not sure how interesting that is, since it's a condition on $Ind(C)$ rather than on $C$ itself.

Comment: @TimCampion thanks for your comments! I don't think it's equivalent to ask for a weakly terminal object in the Ind-completion: you only need maps from all objects in C, not from all Ind-objects. For example, the category of finite sets and injective maps has the category of all sets an injective maps as it's Ind-completion. The latter has no weakly terminal object, but any infinite set admits maps from all finite sets.

Comment: @TimCampion Re. your second comment: I think directedness of the Ind-completion is sufficient, with no AP required. You can extend the argument in my "easy observation 3" transfinitely, using the fact that the Ind-completion has all small filtered colimits. Is directedness of the Ind-completion also necessary? I'm not sure.

Comment: Following up on my last comment: no, directedness of the Ind-completion is not necessary. The free category generated by the directed graph $(\omega+\omega,<)$ has an Ind-object with full support (it satisfies sufficient condition 3 in my question), but its Ind-completion is not directed.